# Find an match similar elements in two columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, logic, sequence

I have a data set like:

```
Column1                Column2
 a bc                    cdr
 cd r                    ab c
 bose                    beats
 bea ts                  bo se
 i phone                 sam sung
 samsung                 iphone
```

If you notice both columns contains almost similar words, but are different in terms of format and have spaces in them. I want techniques such as Cosine Similarity or sequence matcher to match these to columns such that the results becomes like this:

```
column 1                 column 2 
a bc                      ab c
cd r                      cdr 
bose                      bo se
bea ts                    beats
i phone                   iphone
samsung                   sam sung
```

Please not, this is just a sample data, the strings are more complex than these. 
How can I leverage packages such as Cosine Similarity and Sequence Matcher to make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a strong native `pandas` approach to this problem.  I'd recommend using the `fuzzywuzzy` library to solve this.  Make sure you `pip install fuzzywuzzy` first.

By default, this library uses the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) for string similarity.

---

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

res = [process.extractOne(w, df.Column2)[0] for w in df.Column1]
df.assign(Column2=res)
```

```
   Column1   Column2
0     a bc      ab c
1     cd r       cdr
2     bose     bo se
3   bea ts     beats
4  i phone    iphone
5  samsung  sam sung
```

Comment: Takes insane amount of time to complete though

Comment: Yep. The runtime is O(n^2). There are faster implementations of the Levenshtein distance available.